# SQL Server simultaneously fetching from two tables from one connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, odbc, fetch

I have an ODBC connection to SQL Server.
I have a transaction.
Inside the transaction I'm fetching some data in a loop.
Inside the loop I'd like to fetch some other data depending on the previous data.
**And when I try to fetch next data in the next iteration of the loop, it returns like there is no other data, but there is**

Is it possible to do what I do? I must mention that I can't use another connection to fetch other data in the loop - because I need to use transaction.

**Update:**
When I try to fetch first data, I create SQLHSTMT, allocate it, SQLExecDirect it, SQLFetch it, and then SQLGetDataColumns from it. After first fetched row, I create another SQLHSTMT, allocate it, SQLExecDirect it, SQLFetch it and SQLGetDataColumns it. After that I try to call SQLFetch with first statement but it returns that there is no data, but there is!

Comment: I have no Idea what your attempt looks like but a Common Table Expression may assist you.

Comment: My first thought is you should see if you can rethink this process and not use a loop. It is impossible to offer much advice here because you didn't provide any details.

Comment: thank you for trying help me. I've provided some details.

Comment: Those details might tell you something but for the rest of us it means nothing. You might take a look here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Sounds like [MARS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345109%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). Is it on?

Comment: MARS is exactly what I need to know. Thanks a lot. Could you post an answer, that I could mark it as a solution?